# Access entity reference in Block Plugin

Tags: nodes, 8, blocks

I have a content type that has an entity reference field. It's a content type for news articles with a field for tagging the article with taxonomy terms.

I'm attempting to access these terms in a block plugin, however I'm having difficulty. Getting other fields like text fields, and dates work just fine. For example

```
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    $node->get('body')->value
```

Successfully returns the contents of the node's body
 but when I use:

```
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    $tags = $node->get('field_tags')->value;
```

$tags comes up empty.

```
 die(print_r($tags));
```

Does not display anything.
I know it's in there somewhere though because when I use

```
die(print_r($node));
```

I do see the tag id's in there.

Is there a way to display the value of an entity reference field for taxonomy terms, in a block plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

->value is what most field types use but it is in no way restricted to that, they can use whatever they want.

What you want is $node->get('field_tags')->target_id for the ID or $node->get('field_tags')->entity for the referenced term object. You can also loop over it with foreach ($node->get('field_tags') as $item) and then $item->target_id/entity.

As always, have a look at the amazing Entity cheat-sheet here: https://wizzlern.nl/drupal/drupal-8-entity-cheat-sheet for more examples and info.

Answer (score 1):

I found that in order to get the values I had to use getValue() instead of ->value like so:

```
$tags = $node->get('field_tags')->getValue();
```